# Variable scoping c#

Tags: c#, xml, methods, parameters

I am fairly new to c# and am getting an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I am creating an XML packet and sending it to an external device for control. If I put the following code on the form in a click event it works beautifully.
On the btn Click event it looks like this:

```
        SetTestInfoResponse testDataDs = null;
        TestInformation testInfo = null;
        this.PopulateTestDataXml();
        string stringRequestXML = string.Empty;
        string stringResponseXML = string.Empty;


        //Creates Request packet
        stringRequestXML = XMLCommunicationPackets.SetTestInformation (testInfo, testInfo.TestID, testInfo.TestUser, testInfo.TestSampleType, testInfo.TestSampleId, testInfo.TestMethodNumber, testInfo.TestTubeSn, testInfo.TestComments); 
        //Write set Test Info XML Packet and get response for ack or failure.
        stringResponseXML = PluginContext.GetInstance().InstrumentDriverCurrent.GetInstrumentControl().SetCommonParameter(stringRequestXML);
```

However, If I move my entire function out of the form and try to call it when clicking a button I get the error.

written in a method off the form in a .cs file it reads:

```
public static SetTestInfoResponse SetTestData()
    {
        SetTestInfoResponse testDataDs = null;
        TestInformation testInfo = null;

        string stringRequestXML = string.Empty;
        string stringResponseXML = string.Empty;


        //Creates Request packet
        stringRequestXML = XMLCommunicationPackets.SetTestInformation (testInfo, testInfo.TestID, testInfo.TestUser, testInfo.TestSampleType, testInfo.TestSampleId, testInfo.TestMethodNumber, testInfo.TestTubeSn, testInfo.TestComments); 
        //Write set Test Info XML Packet and get response for ack or failure.
        stringResponseXML = PluginContext.GetInstance().InstrumentDriverCurrent.GetInstrumentControl().SetCommonParameter(stringRequestXML);
```

The error occurs when building stringRequestXml.

Part of my problem is the PopulateTestData() is a method on the form itself. Its purpose is to take data from txtboxes and cmbboxes and assign them to their respective arguments..

```
private TestInformation PopulateTestDataXml()
    {
        TestInformation UiTestData = new TestInformation();
        UiTestData.TestID = txtTestId.Text;
        UiTestData.TestUser = cmbUsers.SelectedItem.ToString();
        UiTestData.TestSampleType = txtSampleType.Text;
        UiTestData.TestSampleId = txtSampleId.Text;
        UiTestData.TestMethodNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cmbMethod.SelectedItem);
        UiTestData.TestTubeSn = txtTubeSerialNum.Text;
        UiTestData.TestComments = txtComments.Text;
        return UiTestData;

    }
```

Here is the SetTestInformation() method where I am getting the error:

```
 public static string SetTestInformation(TestInformation testInfo, string stringTestId, string stringUser, string stringSampleType, string stringSampleId, int intMethodNumber, string stringTubeSn, string stringComments)
    {
        try
        { 
            string stringRequestXMLPacket = string.Empty; 
            string stringType = @"Request";
            string stringCommand = @"Set";
            string stringArgument = @"TestInformation"; 

            CommunicationPacket requestXMLPacket = new CommunicationPacket(stringRootTag, stringXMLVersion, stringType, stringCommand);
            requestXMLPacket.AddCommandArgument(stringArgument);

            requestXMLPacket.AddArgumentItem(stringArgument, "sTestId", testInfo.TestID.ToString());
            requestXMLPacket.AddArgumentItem(stringArgument, "sUser", testInfo.TestUser.ToString());
            requestXMLPacket.AddArgumentItem(stringArgument, "sSampleType", testInfo.TestSampleType.ToString());
            requestXMLPacket.AddArgumentItem(stringArgument, "sSampleId", testInfo.TestSampleId.ToString());
            requestXMLPacket.AddArgumentItem(stringArgument, "nMethodNumber", testInfo.TestMethodNumber.ToString());
            requestXMLPacket.AddArgumentItem(stringArgument, "sTubeSn", testInfo.TestTubeSn.ToString());
            requestXMLPacket.AddArgumentItem(stringArgument, "sComments", testInfo.TestComments.ToString());


            stringRequestXMLPacket = requestXMLPacket.CreateXMLPacket();
            return stringRequestXMLPacket;



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Iknow I am having trouble with the variable scope here. I still have to use the method PopulateTestDataXml on the form before I call the setTestData() method. But when I call the Method I have to declare testInfo = null or the parameters for SetTestInformation are not valid ("Does not exist in the current context"). What would I need to pass and how for this to work as a called method on the form btn click? I need to do this as I have alot of deserializing functions written as well to catch error messages in the response xml (these all work fine) and its just too much info on the click event. (And I need to learn).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your examples should work (regardless of where you put them). This is simply incorrect:

```
TestInformation testInfo = null;
// ...
stringRequestXML = XMLCommunicationPackets.SetTestInformation (testInfo, 
                                               testInfo.TestID, ...);
//                                                     ^^ BANG!
```

Your `testInfo` object is `null`. When you try and access *anything* on a `null` object.. a `NullReferenceException` is thrown. You need to initialize it first. You're trying to do that in your `PopulateTestDataXml` method.. which returns the object your after. So change your code to this:

```
TestInformation testInfo = PopulateTestDataXml(); // assign it
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem..

```
public static SetTestInfoResponse SetTestData()
{
    SetTestInfoResponse testDataDs = null;
    TestInformation testInfo = null;

    string stringRequestXML = string.Empty;
    string stringResponseXML = string.Empty;


    //Creates Request packet
    stringRequestXML = XMLCommunicationPackets.SetTestInformation (testInfo, testInfo.TestID, testInfo.TestUser, testInfo.TestSampleType, testInfo.TestSampleId, testInfo.TestMethodNumber, testInfo.TestTubeSn, testInfo.TestComments); 
    //Write set Test Info XML Packet and get response for ack or failure.
    stringResponseXML = PluginContext.GetInstance().InstrumentDriverCurrent.GetInstrumentControl().SetCommonParameter(stringRequestXML);
```

Are you assigning values for these objects I see they are just declared but never assigned.

```
  SetTestInfoResponse testDataDs = null;
  TestInformation testInfo = null;
```

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I was not passing a value to SetTestData

Answer (score 0):

i don't see you use null objects, so i'm wonder if you set them later, also u said the error happen on

```
private TestInformation PopulateTestDataXml()
{
    TestInformation UiTestData = new TestInformation();
    UiTestData.TestID = txtTestId.Text;
    UiTestData.TestUser = cmbUsers.SelectedItem.ToString();
    UiTestData.TestSampleType = txtSampleType.Text;
    UiTestData.TestSampleId = txtSampleId.Text;
    UiTestData.TestMethodNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cmbMethod.SelectedItem);
    UiTestData.TestTubeSn = txtTubeSerialNum.Text;
    UiTestData.TestComments = txtComments.Text;
    return UiTestData;

}
```

after moving it out of your form, which mean possibly it's text box references is broken...
so what you can do, is store a pointer, like in your program.cs where you call your form to show up, 
you can create an static object of form, and then put it in your class, then set it in program.cs file like :

Form1 f=new Form();
MyClass.staticFormPointer = f;

and also replace (new Form()), with (f) on the calling method, 
your my class is like this:

```
class MyClass{
    public static Form1 staticFormPointer = null;
    //your code
    . 
    .
    .
// and in your methods you call it like this txtBox1.Text -> staticFormPointer.txtBox1.Text
}
```